# What effect does the article 'a' have on this fragment?

Tags: articles

What do you think is the difference between:

> Achieve better work/life balance

and

> Achieve a better work/life balance

The discussion may be academic, but I know what my preference is, and I need to be able to defend it.

Comment: What do *you* think the difference is? And how would you defend that position?

Comment: I was somewhat deliciously vague for a reason. This phrase is in a professional body of work, specifically a reference architecture. I make the distinction between the two as the first is an ongoing endeavor and the second is a goal.

Answer (score 1):

I'd posit that the second is more readable, since it gives the reader the early hint: "Achieve a better... {something}"  The reader already knows it will be a singular thing that is better.

Meanwhile, the first example requires the reader to read the entire phrase, then calculate/ponder until the meaning becomes clear:  "Achieve better work.."  --not yet clear-- "..better work/life.." --still calculating the meaning-- .."balance." --now recalculate the whole phrase-- and then the meaning appears.

Obviously not a tremendous difference, but a difference nonetheless.

Comment: Being both readable and understandable as you said, the second one is less "cro-magnon". The addition of A is an article and it help to connect words in sentences so they are clearer. The clearer the better, not to be redundant, but in this case, helps to understand faster.

Answer (score 0):

Both are readily understandable but my preference is for the inclusion of 'a.' You are saying "achieve a better balance between work and life" (presumably work as a proportion of life!)